# Roku HLS Offline Detection

Tags: video-streaming, offline, http-live-streaming, roku, brightscript

So I've gotten HLS to work with my roku box, and have figured out how to write and encode it using the XML file. But I'm trying to write an if statement to detect when the HLS stream is offline with something like isStreamStarted() or perhaps with isRequestFailed() so something like:

```
if isRequestFailed() = -5
print "The stream is currently offline"
end if
```

Would this work? If so, where and which Source file would you recommend this being placed? 
We're using the video player template for our channel.

When i'm connected to the debugging console - and I click on one of the offline HLS streams it gives me the output of

```
"ButtonPressed
showHomeScreen | msg = ConnectionContext failure | index = 0
Video status: 0 0
showHomeScreen | msg = Unspecified or invalid track path/url. | index = 0
Video status: 0 0
showHomeScreen | msg = | index = -5
Video request failure: -5 1
showHomeScreen | msg = | index = 0
Screen closed"
```

If you need to see the code, I can post that as well, but I really haven't made many changes from the original Video player template.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem by doing a separate [roUrlTransfer](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roUrlTransfer) request to the HLS manifest url first, to check if the manifest is available, before doing anything with the video player.

The information you get through [roUrlEvent](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roUrlEvent) callbacks is more clear and complete than what you get from [roVideoPlayerEvent](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roVideoPlayerEvent) in my experience.

The drawback of this approach is that if there are no problems, you've just done an extra manifest request to your video platform, which is going to be repeated by the video player when you start it afterwards for the actual video playback. This slightly increases the load on the video platform.

Another drawback is that this approach will not test or detect any issues with the availability of the video chunks in the manifest. That is still up to the video player.

Example code:

```
Sub playVideo()

    'Request the manifest.
    resultObject = performUrlTransfer("http://urlofyourvideostream.com/hls.m3u8")

    if (resultObject.responseCode = 200)
        'TODO: Play the video in roVideoScreen.
    else
        'TODO: Show an error message.
    end if

End Sub


Function performUrlTransfer(urlString as String) as Object

    urlTransfer = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
    urlTransfer.SetMessagePort(CreateObject("roMessagePort"))
    urlTransfer.SetUrl(urlString)                                   'Set the url.
    urlTransfer.EnableEncodings(true)                               'Enable gzip compression.
    urlTransfer.RetainBodyOnError(true)                             'Also return the response body in case of errors.
    urlTransfer.SetCertificatesFile("common:/certs/ca-bundle.crt")  'Enable https.
    urlTransfer.InitClientCertificates()                            'Enable https.

    'Perform a HTTP GET.
    urlTransfer.AsyncGetToString()

    'Prepare the object that is to be returned.
    resultObject = CreateObject("roAssociativeArray")

    while true
        message = wait(0, urlTransfer.GetMessagePort())

        if (type(message) = "roUrlEvent")

            resultObject.responseCode = message.GetResponseCode()
            resultObject.failureReason = message.GetFailureReason()
            resultObject.bodyString = message.GetString()

            exit while
        end if
    end while

    return resultObject

End Function
```

Comment: Can you provide me with the code that you were able to do this with? I found the roUrlTransfer, but I'm not quite sure what to edit.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include sample code. The code doesn't go into full detail, but should give you enough information.